# Redirect user to authenticated page that uses forms authentication, using HTTP Location Header, HttpWebRequest/Response and Response.Cookies.Add()

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, http-headers

I need to autheticate on a site using forms authentication and then redirect the user to that site along with the session cookie.  I have not figured out how to successfully do this.  Here's my code so far.. I still get redirected to that apps login page.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string data = "nickname=&login={0}&password={1}&action_login.x=70&action_login.y=14action_login=Login";
 string postdata = String.Format(data, "test", "test");
 string page = @"http://1.1.1.1/home.asp";
 string loginPage = @"http://1.1.1.1/auth.asp";
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginPage);
 request.Method = "POST";
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
 ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding(); //encoder
 byte[] requestData = encoding.GetBytes(postdata); //encode post data
 request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
 //write the post data to the request
 Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
 // Send the data.
 requestStream.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
 requestStream.Close();
 try
 {
  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
  string cookieHeader = response.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
  string cookieValue = cookieHeader.Replace("pp_session_id=", "");
  HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("pp_session_id",cookieValue);
  cookie.Domain = "1.1.1.1";
  cookie.Path = "/";
  Response.Clear();
  Response.StatusCode = 302;
  //Response.AddHeader("Set-Cookie", cookieHeader);
  Response.AddHeader("Location",page);
  Response.RedirectLocation = page;
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
  Response.Flush();

 }
 catch (WebException ex)
 {
  Response.Write(ex.Message);
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share how you eventually resolved this. I am in the process of implementing some sort of single signon system and am stuck here. I need to automatically login a user with known credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebug on Mozilla Firefox to see what exactly the browser does when logging into the webapp. Then simulate the same sequence through code.

Or, you can use wireshark to sniff the requests sent by the browser.

One thing I can see from your code, is that you are adding the cookie explicitly. You shouldnt be doing this. You should set a CookieContainer on the request, so that the cookies get sent with all the requests to that site.

hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, on reading your question again, I think I did not fully understand it. What you are trying to do, is use a man-in-the-middle, which does the FBA auth to the back end ASP application, and then passes on that cookie to the client. In doing so, it sets the domain and the path appropriately.

I would suggest you do a network sniff, between your asp.net app and the remote ASP app, as well as from a browser going directly to the asp app. And see what is the difference in the cookies/urls etc

Comment: Is it possible that the ASP server is encoding the hostname of the client (in this case the asp.net app) in the cookie, so it rejects the request when it comes from the client.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I have analyzed the traffic with fiddler2, the only thing missing was the P3P header, but it doesn't seem to attach the cookie on to the redirect request.  The ASP application is third party, so I have no idea how it creates the session id.

The reason I'm looking into this is I'm writing a reverse proxy and I'm unable to get a specific Java Applet to run, so I'd like to launch a direct connection for the user without them having to authenticate.

Comment: Did you get a network sniff from the browser -> proxy, as well as from proxy -> asp.net server?

Are you sure the cookie is being sent from proxy -> ASP app?

Do you have any control over the ASP server? Is it possible to find out why the server does not like the cookie you sent?

Comment: Ok, on reading your code again, I think there is a bug in the way you are doing things.

Assume that your aspnet  server is at address 1.2.3.4. From here, you are trying to do an FBA to 1.1.1.1. You are taking the cookie sent by the backend, and sending it onward to theh browser.

When the browser gets the cookie, the domain will be 1.1.1.1, however the browser was talking to server 1.2.3.4 (middle-man). So, the browser will not accept that cookie. If it did so, then it would be possible to pollute anybody's cookie cache.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  My other option was to try a javascript XMLHttpRequest to the remote site, but I'm limited by the cross-domain restrictions in each browser...

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using the [`FormsAuthentication`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.aspx) class? In particular, have you tried the following sequence (or a variation of it):

`FormsAuthentication.`[`Authenticate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx)`();`

`FormsAuthentication.`[`SetAuthCookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx)`();`

`FormsAuthentication.`[`RedirectFromLoginPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirectfromloginpage.aspx)`();`

Comment: Becuase the remote site is not an ASP.NET application

Answer (score 0):

i believe you have to do a request to an authenticated page on the remote web app.

you'll have to grab the cookie it gives you so you have a valid session. aspnet session id is passed in the cookie. Then you will need to pass the username and password required for that app along with the cookie you received so you will have a valid authenticated session.